# Values are not being validated against openani-generated enum inside spring-boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi-generator

I am using `openapi 3.0.3` spec with `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` for Java code generation to build interfaces that are implemented in a spring-boot project.

```
/user/search:
  get:
    parameters:
      - in: query
        name: sortBy
        description: Field to sort by
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/UserSearchSortBy"
# omitting some code to shorted the copy-pasted spec
schemas:
  UserSearchSortBy:
    type: string
    enum: [first_name, last_name, email, phone_number]
```

The above results in an interface that I can implement. The enum for `UserSearchSortBy` is created fine.

```
@RequestMapping(
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    value = "/user/search",
    produces = { "application/json" }
)
default ResponseEntity<UsersResponsePageableModel> _searchUsers(
    @NotNull @Min(1) @Parameter(name = "currentPage", description = "Page number", required = true) @Valid @RequestParam(value = "currentPage", required = true) Integer currentPage,
    @NotNull @Min(1) @Max(100) @Parameter(name = "pageSize", description = "Number of records to show per page", required = true) @Valid @RequestParam(value = "pageSize", required = true) Integer pageSize,
    @NotNull @Parameter(name = "sortOrder", description = "Sort order", required = true) @Valid @RequestParam(value = "sortOrder", required = true) SortOrderEnumModel sortOrder,
    @NotNull @Parameter(name = "sortBy", description = "Field to sort by", required = true) @Valid @RequestParam(value = "sortBy", required = true) UserSearchSortByModel sortBy,
    @NotNull @Size(max = 128) @Parameter(name = "searchQuery", description = "Search field", required = true) @Valid @RequestParam(value = "searchQuery", required = true) String searchQuery
) {
    return searchUsers(currentPage, pageSize, sortOrder, sortBy, searchQuery);
}
```

I expect the values that are being submitted to an API to be validated against the `UserSearchSortBy` enum. The issue is that there is no validation present. It looks like the generator is not generating a piece that is responsible for validating values against the enum. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following [post](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-type-conversions) helped me to create a converter factory.

```
@Component
public class StringToEnumConverterFactory implements ConverterFactory<String, Enum> {

    private static class StringToEnumConverter<T extends Enum> implements Converter<String, T> {
        private Class<T> enumType;
        public StringToEnumConverter(Class<T> enumType) {
            this.enumType = enumType;
        }
        public T convert(String source) {
            return (T) Enum.valueOf(this.enumType, source.trim().toUpperCase());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public <T extends Enum> Converter<String, T> getConverter(Class<T> targetType) {
        return new StringToEnumConverter(targetType);
    }
}
```

And the following exception handler helps me craft a nice-looking error response.

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class)
public ResponseEntity<?> handleMismatchException(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException e) {
    String message = e.getMessage();
    Class<?> parameterType = e.getParameter().getParameterType();
    if (parameterType.isEnum()) {
        Object[] enumConstants = parameterType.getEnumConstants();
        if (enumConstants != null && enumConstants.length > 0) {
            if (e.getName() != null && !e.getName().isEmpty() && e.getValue() != null) {
                message = String.format("Invalid value '%s' for field '%s'.", e.getValue(), e.getName()) + " Valid values are " + Arrays.asList(enumConstants);
            }
        }
    }
    Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
    errors.put("message", message);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).header("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).body(errors);
}
```